# AdSense sent an email saying my account has been approved when it already was approved

Tags: google-adsense

My account has been approved and running adverts for quite sometime now. However, today I just got a message (it seems legitimate) from Google AdSense saying:

> Congratulations, your AdSense account has been approved to show
>   AdSense ads on your own website. Within a few hours, you will begin to
>   see live ads.

Should I be concerned? They say that they review accounts to check for compliance, could this be some weird way of saying they rechecked my sites and they complied?

Comment: Did you get this message via email, as opposed to within the AdSense website?

Comment: It came via email.

Comment: No, need too worry about this only one thing.
Is your Adsense account is an hosted account or a fully active account ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should be worried.  Once your account is activated, all the communication that AdSense sends you through email is also shown in the web interface of your AdSense account.

This duplicate email seems most likely to be caused by a bug of some sort.  I can't imagine that anything negative will come of it.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to worry about this because it might just be a delayed message or caused by a bug in the system
And you'r saying your account is alreday acctivated so no need to worry but make sure that ads you have created or public(if you have any)